# Loop initilized attributes inside an `class` definition body

Tags: python-3.x

How to Loop initilized attributes inside an `class` definition body?

Supposed a class:

```
class WakeUp:
    def __init__(self,date,time):
        self.date = str(date)
        self.time = str(time)
        self.brush_teeth = brushteeth
        .
        .

    def get_wakeup_activities(self):
        return 'date: ' + self.date + 'time' + self.time. + 'brush_teeth', + self.brush_teeth
```

I intend to avoid the verbose typing, expect to refactor the method as:

```
    def get_wakeup_activities(self):
        act_list = ()
        for attr in attrs:
            act_list.append(attr)
        return 'date: %s time:%s brush_teeth: %s' %tuple(act_list)
```

When the method is called, outputs

```
date:2017-10-17 time:11:50:27 ...
```

or more abstract:

```
def get_wakeup_activities(self):

    wakeup_dict = {k:v for k, v in self.attrs}
    return wakeup_dict
```

While command to call:

```
today_wakeup = Wakeup
today_wakeup.get_wakeup_activities()
```

Outputs:

```
{date:2017-10-17, time:11:50:27,....}
```

Comment: Side-note: If you're going for brevity  (avoiding type `self` over and over) you can use modern string formatting for this purpose, changing the string version to `return 'date: {0.date} time: {0.time} brush_teeth: {0.brush_teeth}'.format(self)` Still repeats the header and name, but it's something.

Comment: a practical nudge @ShadowRanger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class WakeUp:
    def __init__(self,date,time, brushteeth):
        self.date = str(date)
        self.time = str(time)
        self.brush_teeth = brushteeth

    def get_wakeup_activities(self):
        return self.__dict__

today_wakeup = WakeUp('today', '8am', 'YES!')
print(today_wakeup.get_wakeup_activities())
```